# Has the reproducibility crisis affected confidence intervals as well?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, reproducible-research, replicability

The [reproducibility crisis](http://blogs.discovermagazine.com/neuroskeptic/2015/11/10/reproducibility-crisis-the-plot-thickens/#.W-mWc5NKiUn) has given many pause over the value (?) of $p$-values to measure the relevance of statistical findings. Given the interpretation of a $p$-value and some knowledge of probability, it's not surprising to see how many confirmatory studies fail to show $p<0.05$ when the originating study had $p<0.05$ (guaranteed at a rate much higher than $0.05$). The  bit I struggle with is whether that in fact *confirms or disproves the originating study.*

One thought is: why aren't these studies being compared in terms of their confidence intervals? If the originating study is declared statistically significant on the basis of a 95% CI not including the null hypothesized value (equivalent to $p$-value based inference), it seems much more plausible that a confirmatory study would produce an effect which lies within the 95% CI despite lacking statistical significance itself?

Does this imply that the basis for evaluating reproducibility of studies (rather than evaluating statistical significance) is wrong?

Comment: Very relevant: http://datacolada.org/47

Comment: Harry Crane adds some really interesting thoughts on this discussion on a slightly different yet closely connected debate. Check [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07801).